# UITableViewCell "OnClick" Method for iPad

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uitableview

I am well aware there is no literal method called "OnClick" for UITableViewCell, but I need something that works similarly. I have a table, and am populating the table with file names of .pdf files, so I need to set it up where where the user clicks on the row, it will open up the .pdf. The opening part I can handle on my own, but I can't seem to get it to respond to being selected. I thought I found a few lines of code that would work, but it just doesn't respond, so perhaps I'm simply putting it in the wrong spot. any help would be appreciated. I am working with a standard view based application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you just need to know when someone selects a row in your table? Not individual items within a cell?

If so then UITableViews have a delegate method of `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`. Implement that in your tableView's delegate and it'll be called each time someone selects a row.

Comment: I tried that, but I think I missed something. It appears as though you mention two steps, one where I place that particular code, and another step where I implement it in the delegate. I imagine the first step goes in the .m file, where and how do I implement it?

To answer your first question, if I can get it to execute code when any cell is clicked, and I can get the text of that cell, then that is exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: UITableViews allow you to set a delegate and a datasource. The datasource will need methods like `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as it's used to populate the table. The delegate is something you want to be told when things happen; like the user selects a row. In interface builder (.xib files) if you right click on your table you should see you have 'delegate' and 'datasource' as options. I'm assuming you've got datasource linked up if your table is showing data?

Comment: Yes, the datasource is linked to File's Owner. So what do I link the delegate to?

Comment: Ah, I got it. Thanks.

I connected the delegate also to "File's Owner", and added UITableViewDelegate right before UITableViewDataSource in the @interface of the Controller.h file. Thanks for your help, you gave the clues I needed.